# Want to run test on postgresql: psycopg2.OperationalError

Tags: django, postgresql, unit-testing

EDIT 1

have added _test.py with postgresql database connexion data but failed when I run I run the command `py manage.py test cafe.tests.CafeTestCase --settings=core.settings._test`

```
RuntimeWarning: Normally Django will use a connection to the 'postgres' database to avoid running initialization queries against the production database when it's not needed (for example, when running tests). Django was unable to create a connection to the 'postgres' database and will use the first PostgreSQL database instead.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\test.py", line 23, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\test.py", line 53, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\test\runner.py", line 629, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases(aliases=databases)
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\test\runner.py", line 552, in setup_databases
    return _setup_databases(
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 170, in setup_databases
    connection.creation.create_test_db(
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\creation.py", line 58, in create_test_db
    self._create_test_db(verbosity, autoclobber, keepdb)
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\creation.py", line 168, in _create_test_db
    with self._nodb_connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 233, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError
```

---

I have a Django app set with Docker and different developpement environment: dev, preprod, prod.
I use a postgresql database / pgaadmin 4 in my local Windows environment
I want to write and run tests 'outside' Docker in a VSCode terminal

(because if I use web container to run tests, changes in my tests.py are not updated so I need to down, build and re-run my containers)

so I run the command `py manage.py test cafe.tests.CafeTestCase --settings=core.settings.preprod` where I speficy the settings to consider

But I got an error `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: Now` because some data migrations use timezone.now() that i not available in sqlite

but I have specify test_database in my settings and given access to user so test should consider postgresql no?

_test.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "db_preprod",
        "USER": "user_preprod",
        "PASSWORD": "user_preprod",
        "HOST": "localhost",
        "PORT": "5433",
        'TEST' : {
            'NAME': 'test_db_preprod',
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Switch now, you will have to do it eventually.

Comment: Although it does not answer the question I second @BojanKogoj, Postgres is recommended by many expert including the author of ``Two Scoop Of Django`` for Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you just have to create the database (or use an existing database) in your _test.py settings

Answer (score 0):

Since SQLite does not provide the now() function, you need to to replace now() by datetime('now')

Comment: thanksfor replying but I want tests to use postgresql database ; I realize it use SQLite because 'locally' I do not have environment dtabase variables set (thoses in my .env.preprod file)... I have update code above with a _test.py settings file but got another error

Comment: are you running to good database? does db_preprod postgresql database does exist in your postgresql instance?

Comment: I am so stupid... you are right, db_preprod dose not exist